# What is difference between Cryptographic Transformation, Encryption and Hash?

Tags: encryption, hash

I read in a book that: let $f(K,R)$ is cryptographic transformation of $R$ using $K$, $K\{R\}$ means $R$ is encrypted using $K$ and $h\{R\}$ is the hash of $R$ and then the example follows.

I want to know what is difference between cryptographic transformation of $R$ and encryption of $R$ using the same key? Aren't they same thing?

Comment: I'd guess that encryption and hashing are cryptographic transformations, but crypto transformations aren't restricted to encryption and hashing.

Comment: Not sure, but it could be a possible duplicate of [Difference between encrypting something and hashing something](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2887/difference-between-encrypting-something-and-hashing-something) and/or [Can hashing become encrypting](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20148/can-hashing-become-encrypting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a cryptographic transformation can mean anything. It is just a cryptographic function whose output is based on the input, $K$ and $R$ in this case. You could have a $MAC(K, R)$ where the transformation is a message authentication code or MAC for instance. A MAC also takes a key and a message, but its purpose is rather different.

So $K\{R\}$ is a specialization of $f$. Often $K\{R\}$ it is written down as $E(K, R)$ which would probably make this more clear (although $E_k(R)$ is also often used).

---

It could also be that $K\{R\}$ is the keyed encryption function, taking just the input $R$ while $f(K, R)$ is the uninitialized or stateless cipher taking both the key $K$ *and* the input message $R$. If the math notation is not precisely specified you may have to rely on context.

Comment: I'm not sure about the term "specialization" though, maybe there is a better mathematical term for this.

Comment: maybe: "special case"? But "specialization" is also fine according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_case).

Comment: @SOJPM Do you agree on the edit below the horizontal line?

Comment: As the OP didn't (yet) reply, stating this addition is absolutely reasonable as it gives the OP a second way of interpretation if the first (more likely) one doesn't make sense. If your "uninitailized" indicates that you look for a better word, I may suggest "stateless".