# Use HMAC for every block encryption operation

Tags: hash, block-cipher, hmac

Is it possible to use HMAC while performing encryption of blocks?
I think that the main problem with the approach would be to get the same output size as the block, from the HMAC function.
Also, the hash function is one-way, so how would one perform the decryption?
Are there any real-world examples for this approach, or is it not feasible?

Comment: @kelalaka Thanks for your comment.
Also, isn't there a problem with the fact that the hash function is one way?

Comment: I replace every encryption operation on a block, with HMAC function.
But since the hash function is one-way, when I perform the decryption on every block, there is no inverse function, or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, that was my question.
Can I encrypt every block with hash function?
Is it not possible because of what I said about the one-way property of the hashing function?

Comment: Does these answer your question? [Can I say "I have encrypted something" if I hash something?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/73179/can-i-say-i-have-encrypted-something-if-i-hash-something) and [Difference between encrypting something and hashing something](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2887/18298)

Comment: FYI, [CTR mode is designed for PRF](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/85572/18298) and we can use [Hash functions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1656/18298) to generate a keystream and encrypt like OTP manner.